# How to make flutter show complete text

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display the complete text instead of short form. I have made the container big enough and given enough maxLines in Text widget but it doesn't work. I have tried the expanded widget and it doesn't work either.

[image]

This is the Model

```
  class NewsModel {
  String imgUrl;
  String title;
  String description;
  String content;

  NewsModel(
      {@required this.imgUrl,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.description,
      @required this.content});
}
```

Getting the data inside Provider

```
Future<void> getNews(String categoryName) async {
    try {
      String _url;
      news.clear();
      if (categoryName == '') {
        _url =
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&excludeDomains=stackoverflow.com&sortBy=popularity&language=en&apiKey=$_apiKey';
      } else {
        _url =
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=$categoryName&sortBy=popularity&language=en&apiKey=$_apiKey';
      }
      final response = await http.get(_url);
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      if (data['status'] == 'ok') {
        data["articles"].forEach((article) {
          if (article['urlToImage'] != null && article['description'] != null) {
            news.add(NewsModel(
              description: article['description'],
              imgUrl: article['urlToImage'],
              title: article['title'],
              content: article['content'],
            ));
          }
        });
        print('doneeee');
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        print('error');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the page

```
return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/article', arguments: {
                      'description': newslist[index].description,
                      'imgUrl': newslist[index].imgUrl,
                      'title': newslist[index].title,
                      'content': newslist[index].content,
                    });
```

Finally using the Arguments

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args['title']),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Text(args['description']),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 500,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                Text(
                  args['content'],
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 100,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your description doesn't explain your problem every well. We also need to see your code to be able to help you. Check the guidelines to improve your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you use the  RichText Widget? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Comment: The Text widget doesn't add [+968 chars] when it truncates text.  I think your string was truncated at the source instead.

Comment: This is from the source probably. Have seen this on news.org. They truncate the text in free versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free version of the API truncates the text as pointed out in the comments.